# How to limit light to a collection? Formerly (2.79) it was 'Limit to this layer'

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, collections

How to limit light to a collection? Formerly (2.79) it was 'Limit to this layer'. I have a lot of blend-files where I have object and lights in layers and the lights are limited to that layer. With version 2.8 Blender Internal is gone and now I have Eevee, and the formerly "layers" are now "collections" BUT I did not find a way to limit the light behaviour to a collection.